# excel 2010 is appending a space to the end of currency field when saving a csv file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Create an Excel spreadsheet with one cell. Put "$1,234.56" (WITHOUT the quotes) in the first cell. Save it as test.csv. Open test.csv file in a text editor, Notepad.exe will work. The file contains "$1,234.56 " (WITH the quotes). Note that it appended a space after the '6' and before the closing quote. Any idea how to stop this?

Comment: Just a hunch; does your regional settings for monetary values contain an appended space?

Comment: Most likely the space is there to make room for the trailing ) when the number is negative. If you use a different number format, one which doesn't enclose in () when the number is negative, this won't happen. Seems like an undocumented "enhancement".

Answer (score 0):

When I do as you suggest, and then save it in Excel 2013 as a standard "CSV (Comma delimited)" it doesn't append a space.  I don't have 2010 to test with anymore, but I've never seen it append a space like that (by default).  Confirm this behaviour on another Excel 2010 machine, and perhaps while logged into your computer as a different user.  If it does the same thing there, it's an Excel 2010 bug.  If not, it's something specific about your configuration that's adding it and you'll need to narrow it down before we can help you figure out what that configuration problem may be.

As for the quotes, it's adding those because your dollar amount is written as a string (because it's not just numbers when you add `$`, `,` and `.`) which has a comma in it.  Since the string has a comma in it the field is wrapped in quotes so that when you load it into something from that CSV it knows that comma is part of the string value for that field, and not a separator between fields.

Comment: Tried this on Excel 2010 and all I got was `"$1,234.56"`, no spaces.